# Move File also if another user got it locked

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

Hello I got a very simple script to move files, looks like this

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.MoveFile "WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1)
```

It moves files from a shared hard drive , so sometimes the file is open by another user and the script fails.

**I have view some questions with this topic and they just check if the file is locked. So is there a way to remove this lock and move the file?**

Comment: There are a number of "unlock" tools available, so there must be a way to do it. Not sure if it can be done in vbscript though.

Comment: @GeertBellekens you would need to access the Windows API, so maybe a COM wrapper would be able to do it. But there is no "native" VBScript solution.

Comment: If you unlock it then the user who is using it will likely crash, maybe corrupting the file. If a crashed program has it open then terminating the program will unlock it. When a program opens a file it says whether other programs can read or write or neither. So whatever program it is, it is saying don't mess with my file till I'm finished. Type `openfiles /?` for the standard system way.